# C++, co-ordinates on a circle, angles involved, for loop with if loop

Tags: c++, loops, geometry, coordinates

I have this code.

```
for(int j=0; j<=n; j++)
{
  Xnew2 = -j*(Y+R2)/n;
  Ynew2 = pow((((Y+R2)*(Y+R2)) - (Xnew2*Xnew2)), 0.5);

  if(abs(Ynew2) <=R1)
    cout<<"\n("<<Xnew2<<", "<<Ynew2<<")"<<endl;

  AngleB2 = acos(Xnew2/pow((pow(Xnew2, 2))+(pow(Ynew2, 2)), 0.5))* (180/Pi);
  cout<<"\nAngle 'B' = "<<AngleB2<<" Degrees"<<endl;

  AngleV2 = acos(((pow(Xnew2, 2))+(pow(Ynew2, 2))+(pow(100, 2))-(pow(65, 2)))/(200*(pow(((pow(Xnew2, 2))+(pow(Ynew2, 2))), 0.5))))* (180/Pi);
  cout<<"Angle 'V' = "<<AngleV2<<" Degrees"<<endl;

  AngleTheta12 = AngleB2 - AngleV2;
  cout<<"Theta 1 = "<<AngleTheta12<<" Degrees"<<endl;

  AngleTheta22 =(asin(pow(((sin(AngleV2*Pi/180))*(pow(((pow(Xnew2, 2))+(pow(Ynew2, 2))), 0.5))/65), 0.5)))*(180/Pi);
  cout<<"Theta 2 = "<<AngleTheta22<<" Degrees"<<endl;
}
```

We are designing a program for a robot hand to be able to draw the Syastro Letter 'K', which is essentially a Crecent Moon. We have to first calculate points on the curve, and the calculate the angles of the robot arm, as shown above.

I have managed to get my code working when there is no limits involved (When calculating points/angles for the outside line of the shape), but as soon as I try to impose limits into the 'for' loop, it does not give a lost of points, but still lists a lot of angles....

Does anyone have any idea where I am going wrong? I am trying to limit the values so that the 'Y' co-ordinate has to between 310 and -310.

Thanks if you understand this!

Comment: I'm still confused on your problem, you are trying to impose bounds on the Y coordinate in your calculation above, I get that but what do you mean it does not give lots of points but gives lots of angles

Comment: The initial idea was to find out points on a curve using the equation above. We then wanted to impose limits on the Y coordinates to that it would be be between 310 and -310. We would get a list of points. Then use them in the equations. However, now only angles are appearing instead the points AND the angles? was just wondering how to fix. That help?

Comment: how do you determine that only angles appear and not points? For each points in the above calculation, there is an angle associated with it